# excel vba how to change array content by referencing array name

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, pass-by-reference

I am trying to make change to the array named arraySrc in the following manner:

```
Dim arraySrc(0 To 1) As Integer

arraySrc(0) = 1
arraySrc(1) = 2
Dim arrayTmp

arrayTmp = arraySrc
arrayTmp(0) = 0
arrayTmp(1) = 1
```

Actually, I want to use one name as a handle to make change to multiple arrays individually by case, for example, I have a function to return the array name, I want to then set the returned array name to arrayTmp, then make change to arrayTmp directly using the format arrayTmp(0)=0 eg, hoping to make change to the original array

However, by using variant doesn't work. 
Can anybody please let me know how to implement this?

Comment: `Dim arrayTmp` is variant type bye default as you have not declared explicitly the data type. What is not working? What you are doing is changing the values in `arrayTmp`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change values in `arraySrc` you need to refer to the indices of that array.

e.g. which you have already done.

```
arraySrc(0) = 1
arraySrc(1) = 2
```

Just because you copy `arraySrc` to `arrayTmp`, the latter is not going to keep the reference to `arraySrc`.

However this is possible if you had passed a reference of `arraySrc` via a funtion's parameter.

e.g.

```
Option Explicit

Sub myArrays()
Dim arraySrc(0 To 1) As Integer
    arraySrc(0) = 1
    arraySrc(1) = 2
    '-- the referencing
    arrayReference arraySrc
End Sub

Function arrayReference(ByRef varr() As Integer) As Variant
    If Not IsVarArrayEmpty(varr) Then
        varr(0) = 0
        varr(1) = 1
    End If
    arrayReference = varr
End Function

'--check for empty array - additional
Function IsVarArrayEmpty(anArray As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
        i = UBound(anArray, 1)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        IsVarArrayEmpty = False
    Else
        IsVarArrayEmpty = True
    End If
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this? The ByRef argument means that the source array, passed as a parameter will also be changed:

```
Sub test()
Dim arraySrc(0 To 1) As Integer
arraySrc(0) = 1
arraySrc(1) = 2
PassByRef arraySrc
Debug.Print arraySrc(0)
Debug.Print arraySrc(1)
End Sub

Sub PassByRef(ByRef arrayTmp() As Integer)
arrayTmp(0) = 0
arrayTmp(1) = 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, I want to use one name as a handle to make change to multiple arrays individually by case, for example, I need a function to return the array name, then set the return value to arrayTmp, then make change to arrayTmp, hoping to make change to the original array

Comment: I'm still not totally clear from your comment what the inputs and outputs would be. Maybe you should edit your original question to better reflect what you are trying to do. I believe you can use the concept @boncodigo and I have outlined to do it, but can't be sure.

Comment: It is like I need a pointer to the array. I only want to manipulate array content through the pointer, no matter which array the pointer points to. Is this clear?

Comment: @Max C Pointers in VBA? You can pass around a reference to the integer array to functions via the ByRef keyword,which is exactly on the above answers. The AddressOf operator will give you the integer address of a variable, but VBA is unable to do anything with it; it's only useful for passing to a `DLL`.